# Using a List method in c# asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have added a List method for favorite colors for a single user stored in doTableUsers:

```
List<string> colorList = new List<string>();

....

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        idColor = reader["idColor"].ToString();
        colorList.Add(idColor.ToString());
    }

    ns = "";

    foreach (string s in colorList)
    {
        if (ns.Length != 0)
        {
            ns += ", ";
        }
        ns += s;
    }
}
```

Now I need to show it in GridView for a single user of their favorite colors.

If write in code-behind in the Gridview method:

```
Response.Write(str.ToString());
```

In output, I have the correct list of colors:

```
Antique White, Blueviolet, Dark Blue
```

But the parameters passed in query for show the GridView are incorrects, the comma is lost:

```
Antique WhiteBluevioletDark Blue
```

My code below, thank you in advance.

```
    str = null;
    strArr = null;
    count = 0;

    str = ns == null ? "" : ns.ToString();
    char[] splitchar = { ',' };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        strArr = str.Split(splitchar);
    }
    else
    {
        strArr = null;
    }


    for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
    {
       sql = "......";
    }

    DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Server.UrlDecode(strArr[count].Trim()));
                Response.Write(Server.UrlDecode(strArr[count].Trim()));
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer to your question, but

```
ns = "";

foreach (string s in colorList)
{
    if (ns.Length != 0)
    {
        ns += ", ";
    }
    ns += s;
}
```

can be converted into

```
var ns = string.Join(", ", colorList.ToArray());
```

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq, how did this solve the issue in your question?

Comment: @LarsKristensen I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `var newValues = str.Split(',');`

Comment: I already do so... the problem is the parameter in for loop on the query for show the gridview...